# How to create a join condition using a loop?

Tags: python, loops, apache-spark, join, pyspark

I am creating a generic condition for joining 2 dataframes which have the same key and same structure as a code below. I would like to make it as a function for comparing 2 dataframes. First idea, I made it as string condition as it's easy for concatenate the condition with the loop. Finally, it seems like the join condition couldn't accept the string condition. Could somebody please guide me on this?

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

key = "col1 col2 col3"

def CompareData(df1,df2,key) :
  key_list = key.split(" ")
  key_con=""

  for col in key_list:
    condi = "(F.col(\"" + col +"\") == F.col(\""+"x_"+col+"\"))"  # trying to generate generic condition
    key_con=key_con + "&" + condi

  key_condition=key_con.replace('&','',1)

  df1_tmp = df1.select([F.col(c).alias("x_"+c) for c in df1.columns])

  df_compare = df2.join(df1_tmp, key_condition , "left")  # The problem was here. key_condition has error. If I copy the condition string below and place into join condition, it works fine.

  # key_condition = (F.col("col1") == F.col("x_col1")) & (F.col("col2") == F.col("x_col2")) & (F.col("col3") == F.col("x_col3"))
```

Comment: if the column names are same, why not just pass the list of columns? `df1.join(df2, ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], 'left')`

Comment: I've tried but I got ambiguous error for other columns which are not key for joining.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Debug questions require a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
  key_con = F.lit(True)
  for col in key_list:
    condi = (F.col(col) == F.col(f"x_{col}"))
    key_con = key_con & condi
```

In your attempt, your condition is of type *string*. But `join`'s argument `on` only accepts string if it is a plain column name. You are trying to create a column expression and pass it to the `on` argument. Column expression is not the same thing as string, so you need a slightly different method to make a composite column expression.